# python : Converting string of keys followed by values into dictionary

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am working on automating aws management plane security. Their api returns something like below.

[image]

[Here is what I am trying to implement](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_credential_report)

How do I get a list of dictionaries from the `Content` key above? or What data structure I should use so that I can use/read the values of keys efficiently?

### P.S.

*The SO is warning me to ask a question that is clear and well formulated as this question is getting downvotes. I believe this is because I posted an image which is not clear at first glance. I request you all to click on image to see readable image. If I would have posted a data instead of image, formatting would have become worst and I would have lost too much of time formatting it.*

Comment: Don't post text as images, we are unable to read it, copy and paste it, and delete any data that may be private and substitute it by non-real data.

Comment: Can you give a complete example, with both input *and* corresponding output?

Comment: @ScottHunter please see the link I updated in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the `Content` key appears to be a standard CSV format, so you could create a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

data = {u'Content': 'a,b,c\n1,2,3\n4,5,6'}
list_of_dicts = list(csv.DictReader(StringIO(data['Content'])))
print(list_of_dicts)
```

Which for this simple example would give you:

```
[OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]), OrderedDict([('a', '4'), ('b', '5'), ('c', '6')])]
```

Comment: Oh my God! Thanks a lot, Martin.

Comment: `StringIO from io` is somehow throwing error, `StringIO from StringIO` is working.

Comment: `from StringIO import StringIO` is correct when using Python 2.x

Comment: oh... got it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The `content` Entry seems to be composed of `comma-delimited` Values. It may make sense to extract the Values of this Entry and then split the String using a Comma. Consider this trivial Example:

```
strData     = {u"content": "lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, verbatim "}
lstData     = str(strData['content']).split(sep=",")
lstData     = [v.strip() for v in lstData]
print(lstData) # YIELDS: ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'verbatim']
```

Comment: the `Content` is comma separated `keys` followed by comma separated set of `values`